# HBase access from Java API Client

Tags: java, hbase

I'm having some troubles accessing HBase from java API Client and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using HBase 1.1.2 in standalone mode on VM (10.166.205.41) with RHEL6 and JAVA 1.7.
Here is my HBase configuration from the hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>10.166.205.41</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>9091</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/hbaserootdir/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hbaserootdir/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

My regionservers file is defined as followed:

```
10.166.205.41
```

The HBase shell client is working fine and i can access the HBase master UI from url 10.166.205.41:16010.

Here is my Java API Client running on Eclipse on Windows 7. 
Pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
         <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.2</version>
         <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Source code:

```
public class InsertData {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(InsertData.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

        config.setInt("timeout", 120000);
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","10.166.205.41");
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "9091");

        Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);

        Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("emp"));

        try {

            Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("1"));
            Result result = table.get(g);

            byte [] name = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("personal data"), Bytes.toBytes("name"));

            logger.info("name : " + Bytes.toString(name));

        } finally {
            table.close();
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

During execution connection to server 10.166.205.41:41571 failed.

```
2018-12-14 16:35:19 DEBUG FailedServers:56 - Added failed server with address hlzudd5hdf01.yres.ytech/10.166.205.41:41571 to list caused by org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: hlzudd5hdf01.yres.ytech/10.166.205.41:41571
2018-12-14 16:35:19 DEBUG ClientCnxn:843 - Reading reply sessionid:0x167ad4d815d000b, packet:: clientPath:/hbase/meta-region-server serverPath:/hbase/meta-region-server finished:false header:: 3,4  replyHeader:: 3,4697,0  request:: '/hbase/meta-region-server,F  response:: #ffffffff0001a726567696f6e7365727665723a3431353731ffffffa0ffffffe9ffffff80fffffffd5611ffffff8c6a50425546a24a17686c7a7564643568646630312e797265732e797465636810ffffffe3ffffffc4218ffffffceffffff93ffffffb6ffffffeafffffffa2c100183,s{4519,4519,1544800813291,1544800813291,0,0,0,0,77,0,4519} 
2018-12-14 16:35:19 DEBUG ClientCnxn:742 - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x167ad4d815d000b after 38ms
2018-12-14 16:35:19 DEBUG AbstractRpcClient:349 - Not trying to connect to hlzudd5hdf01.yres.ytech/10.166.205.41:41571 this server is in the failed servers list
2018-12-14 16:35:19 DEBUG ClientCnxn:843 - Reading reply sessionid:0x167ad4d815d000b, packet:: clientPath:/hbase/meta-region-server serverPath:/hbase/meta-region-server finished:false header:: 4,4  replyHeader:: 4,4697,0  request:: '/hbase/meta-region-server,F  response:: #ffffffff0001a726567696f6e7365727665723a3431353731ffffffa0ffffffe9ffffff80fffffffd5611ffffff8c6a50425546a24a17686c7a7564643568646630312e797265732e797465636810ffffffe3ffffffc4218ffffffceffffff93ffffffb6ffffffeafffffffa2c100183,s{4519,4519,1544800813291,1544800813291,0,0,0,0,77,0,4519}
```

On the HBase master UI this is the region server address and by clicking on the link i can't get the page neither.
I packaged my program as jar file and running it on my VM is fine which makes me think it could be a port access issue.

Entering netstat -tanp | grep LISTEN command on my RHEL6 VM tells me my region server port is listening

```
tcp        0      0 10.166.205.41:41571         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      26322/java
```

Seems I don't have any firewall running so don't know why the connection failed. Maybe it is something else.

I'm out of idea to fix that issue so if you could help me that would be much appreciated ^^
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're using HBase 1.1.2, you should have Maven dependencies on Hbase 1.1.2. Remove the `hbase` dependency, and change `hbase-client` to be `1.1.2`. Also there's no need to fill in the connection details if `hbase-site.xml` is in your classpath.

Comment: You're right, I was first using HBase 2.1.1 and due to compatibility issue with an other project i switched to version 1.1.2 and i forgot to change the pom dependencies. I did it but i'm still having the same problem. I fill the connection details because the hbase-site.xml was not in my classpath. I tried that way but no changes.

Comment: Are you sure your Zookeeper port isnt `2181`? That's the standard.

Comment: I agree standard is 2181 for zookeeper, but for unknown reason (maybe same as my actual issue) i can't access zookeeper using port 2181. By switching to port 9091 it works

Comment: `9091` is typically used for Kafka bootstrap servers. Unless you've manually changed it when you installed Zookeeper, you should be using `2181`.

Comment: I manually changed Zookeeper port from 2181 to 9091 since 2181 was not working

Comment: But `9091` also isn't working and it should be `2181`. I'd revert those changes, so you're setting this up as vanilla as possible. We can look at any issues after that.

Comment: I changed to default Zookeper port `2181`. Now i can't connect neither to Zookeeper. Here is the stack `2018-12-20 13:26:30 INFO  ClientCnxn:975 - Opening socket connection to server 10.166.205.41/10.166.205.41:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2018-12-20 13:26:51 WARN  ClientCnxn:1102 - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)`

Comment: @NicolasGernigon Did you find a solution to that problem? It seems like I face the same issue.

Comment: @wipman unfortunately not :(